# Математической маятник

Tags: jquery, сss3

И так у нас есть математический маятник

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатие на кнопку запуск к картинке добавляется класс .objectAnimation( он описывает анимацию), надо сделать что колебания маятника со временем затухали!

```js
/*Добавляем на кнопку анимацию*/
$(".st").click(function() {
  $("#Object2").toggleClass("objectAnimation");
});
```

```css
.objectAnimation {
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: 50% 0px;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 550ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(25deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Возможно можно сделать так, чтобы с каждой секундой менялись

```
transform:rotate(25deg);
```

Или как-то так!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите, что бы блок качался больше времени, нужно добавить больше промежных отклонений в CSS

```js
/*Добавляем на кнопку анимацию*/ 
$('button').click(function(){
  clearInterval(time);
  $("#Object2").toggleClass("objectAnimation");
  var time = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#Object2").removeClass("objectAnimation");
  }, 5000); // Указать время, как в CSS
});
```

```css
#Object2 {
  width:10px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-left:250px;
}
.objectAnimation  {
    transform-origin: 50% 0px;
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 5000ms; /* Указать время, как в JS */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-25deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(-25deg);
        }
        10% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(25deg);
        }
        20% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(-20deg);
        }
        30% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(20deg);
        }
        40% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(-15deg);
        }
        50% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(15deg);
        }
        60% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
        }
        70% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
        }
        80% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);
        }
        90% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);
        }
        100% {
          -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Object2"></div>
<button>Раскачать</button>
```